# Templating of a specific post ID

Tags: posts, templates, template-hierarchy

I'd like to know it's possible to do something like this

```
single-post-45.php
```

I needn the post(45) only to have a custom template.

I know we can achieve this with page, like this

```
page-45.php
```

or by a templating file **template-test.php**

But I can't find if it's possible to do this with simple post (following the wordpress hierarchie, i think it's not possible)

https://www.lafabriquedunet.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/templates-wordpress-hierarchie.jpg

Comment: what are you trying to achieve that requires that specific post to have a different template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to follow this file name structure:

```
single-{post-type}-{slug}.php
```

If you have a post names "Hello World" and the slug of post is `hello-world` then the template name will be `single-post-hello-world.php`

**Update:**

There is no default way to use id in template name. But you might try this snipped:

```
<?php
add_filter( 'single_template', 'load_post_template_by_id' );
 
function load_post_template_by_id( $single_template ) {
    global $post;
 
    if ( 'post' === $post->post_type) {
        $tmp_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/single-post-'.$post->ID.'.php';

        if ( file_exists( $tmp_template ) ) {
            $single_template = $tmp_template;
        }
    }
 
    return $single_template;
}
```

Here I'm overriding the post template in a tricky way. Now if you have a post with id `42` and you have a template file named `single-post-42.php` then it should load automatically.

*I didn't test the code. So use it with your own risk.*

Comment: Is is possible now to do with the slug instead of the ID ? If the slug change, then the template will not work

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Wish wordpress will add this feature in some update (even if it's very situational)